# PHP preg_replace, need a REGEX to replace "endofentry" + number + " />"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a quick REGEX to use with preg_replace() in PHP that will remove instances of the string...

"endofentry" + followed by any three digit number + " />" tacked on the end.

any help would be fantastic, thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need to extract the three digit number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to extract the three digit number, then this will work:

```
/(?<=endofentry)[0-9]{3}(?=\/>)/
```

As in:

```
<?php

CONST REGEX = "/(?<=endofentry)[0-9]{3}(?=\/>)/";
$stringSubject = "endofentry456/>";
preg_match(REGEX, $stringSubject, $match);
echo $match[0]; //echo's 456

?>
```

If you need to replace the entire string:

**Update**

```
<?php

CONST REGEX = "/\"endofentry\"[0-9]{3}\/>/";
$stringSubject = "\"endofentry\"567/>";
$stringReplace = "replace_me!";
echo preg_replace(REGEX, $stringReplace, $stringSubject); //echo's replace_me!

?>
```

Comment: There's actually double quotes around the endofentry .. i.e. `"endofentry481"/> more content...` if you could update that second code snippet to support those double quotes, that'd be amazing, thank you!

Comment: cool, figured it out - `preg_replace("/\"endofentry[0-9]{3}\"\/>/", '', $content);`, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/endofentry\\d{3}\\/>/', '', 'endofentry321/> asdfa s');
```

Tested [here](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html)

Comment: hmm, not having much luck with that. There's actually double quotes around the _endofentry_ .. i.e.
`"endofentry481"/> more content...`

if you could update your code to support those double quotes, that'd be amazing!

Comment: @Gareth what is the problem to add those quotes? `'%"endofentry\\d{3}"/>%'` Yes, it's that simple. @DShook It's better to use other delimiters, when you need that character in your regex. That way you don't need to escape it.